# Calculation of Ultrasonic Attenuation Coefficient

Tags: waves, acoustics, attenuation

Hello I have a conceptual question regarding calculating the ultrasonic attenuation coefficient for a transmitted wave within a solid material. I have seen Beer's Law used to calculate the attenuation coefficient:

$$
A = A_0 * e^{-\alpha d}
$$

Rearranging yields
$$
\alpha = -ln(\frac{A}{A_0})*\frac{1}{d}
$$

My question is relating to the A intensities. Since A is frequency dependent, are they the maximum amplitudes in the time domain at a given frequency, or are they the amplitude values of the Fourier Transform, at each respective frequency?

For example, if I send a 1 MHz wave from an emitting sensor through a material with thickness d to a receiving sensor, is the amplitude I am going to use the maximum amplitude of the time-domain waveform and would A_0 be the determined by removing the sample and using that maximum amplitude, giving me a attenuation coefficient value at 1 MHz? For instance, if the Emitter is sending 1 MHz at a maximum amplitude of 5V, and after it propagates through a material that is 1m long the maximum amplitude was 1V, would the attenuation coefficient for 1 MHz be:
$$
\alpha = -ln(\frac{1 V}{5 V})*\frac{1}{1m} = 1.609 \frac{Neper}{m}
$$
And then repeat this for 1.1 MHz and so forth up to 5 MHz as an example?

**OR**

Would I convert the received time-domain waveforms to the frequency domain using the FFT to get an amplitude at each freuqency. Using these amplitudes would I solve the attenuation coefficient for whatever freuqency range I chose, such as from 1 MHz up to let say 5 MHz using the amplitude values the FFT gave at each frequency?

I drew a quick schematic of what I meant:

[image]

Comment: I believe that due to the linearity of the Fourier transform ([Parseval’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem) is relevant here) since the amplitude of a frequency component is directly equivalent to that in the time domain (for this frequency component), the two methods are equivalent. Still, the second (FFT) will save you some time since you’ll be doing all measurements in a single pass. Of course, in practice, there may be some differences due to transducer nonlinearities depending on the signal amplitude, and other factors but the results should be very similar.

Comment: I never thought of it like that, thank you very much :)

Comment: Please, by all means, verify that yourself. This is what my intuition tells me but there is a possibility that I have missed or misunderstood something so do **not** count on this as being definitive! Plus, one request: If you manage to find a solution to your problem, do spend some time to answer your question and accept the answer as the correct one so that people with similar issues can benefit from it in the future and you can reference it in the future.